# Как изменять размер окна под разные вкладки QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qtabwidget

Примерно так должно выглядеть:

[image: Первая вкладка должна выглядеть примерно так]

[image: Вторая вкладка должна выглядеть примерно так]

Код:

**testui.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(726, 461)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 351, 381))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(353, 0, 351, 381))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.widget, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Что то маленькое"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Вкладочка 1"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Noto Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Что то большое</p></body></html>"))

        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Noto Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Нужно подстраивать окно под обе вкладки по размеру что бы небыло пустых мест</p>\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))

        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.widget), _translate("MainWindow", "Вкладочка 2"))
```

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from testui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # Settings
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Нужно при переключении вкладок изменять размер окна под размер содержимого вкладки.

Как мне это организовать? Спасибо

надеюсь понятно изложил и организовал пост :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен что правильно вас понял, но попробуйте.

> void QWidget::**setFixedSize**(const QSize &**`s`**)
>
> Устанавливает как минимальный, так и максимальный размер виджета равным **`s`**, тем самым предотвращая его увеличение или уменьшение. 
> Это переопределит ограничения размера по умолчанию, установленные `QLayout`...

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

#from testui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(726, 461)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 351, 381))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(353, 0, 351, 381))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.widget, "")
        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
#        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Что то маленькое"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Вкладочка 1"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Noto Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Что то большое</p></body></html>"))

        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Noto Sans\'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Нужно подстраивать окно под обе вкладки по размеру что бы небыло пустых мест</p>\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))

        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.widget), _translate("MainWindow", "Вкладочка 2"))
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.current_changed)       # +++
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)                                 # +++
        
        
    def current_changed(self, index):                                     # +++
        if index == 1:
            self.setFixedSize(726, 461)
        elif index == 0:
            self.setFixedSize(726, 129)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Для моих задач должно подойти.

Comment: @DeSkree пожалуйста.